# How to recognize a users touch in relation to a given path in Gideros

Tags: android, iphone, path, lua, coordinates

I am tasked with creating a game that's based on mobile devices. I am using "Gideros studio", developing in "Lua".
I have an image on the screen, example the letter C. The C has a given stroke path, number of coordinates that the user must trace along.

How do you check to see whether or not the user is tracing correctly. I would compare arrays, but the user is allowed to go off the path by about "10px-20px".

The line is curved as well of course being the letter C. What best concept can I use for this task?

I thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is too broad, not specific to Lua: you need to look for "pattern recognition" for writing, not a simple topic.